# Как передать входные параметры в функцию

Tags: c++, функции, c++11, командная-строка

Есть main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    // Получение параметров запуска
    StartArgs startArgs;
    startArgs.SetArgs(argc, ...);
}
```

И есть класс:

```
class StartArgs{
        private:
            char operationType = '0';
            std::string inputFile = "";
            std::string outputFile = "";
        public:
            void SetArgs(int argc, char *argv[]){
                if (argc > 3) std::cout << "Ошибка считывания аргументов" << std::endl;
                else {
                    for (int argnum = 0; argnum < argc; argnum++){
                       if (strncmp(argv[argnum], "-d", 2 )) operationType = '1';
                       else if (outputFile == "") outputFile = argv[argnum];
                       else if (inputFile  == "") inputFile  = argv[argnum];
                       else std::cout << "Ошибка считывания аргументов" << std::endl;
                    }
                }
            }
    };
```

Вопрос:

Что должно быть вместо ... в *startArgs.SetArgs(argc, ...);*

Comment: Даже непонятно, а в чем проблема? Или почему?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Просто

```
startArgs.SetArgs(argc, argv);
```

Но, советую, опишите свою функцию как

```
void SetArgs(int argc, const char *argv[])
```

(она не изменяет строки, на которые указывает `argv`)

`main` как

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
```

и опять же передавайте `argv`...

Comment: По поводу `main` разрешите не согласиться. У нее есть две стандартных сигнатуры: `int main () { body }` и `int main (int argc, char *argv[]) { body }` ([1](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function)). Остальные варианты - это implementation-defined.